# Doctrine2 with MS Server pagination and order by not working under ZF2

Tags: php, sql-server, doctrine-orm, pagination, zend-framework2

I have a list of news ordered by the published date and I want to paginate it. I am using Doctrine 2.5 in a Zend Framework 2 project. Here's my entity:

```
<?php

namespace BuscadorJuridico\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Zend\Form\Annotation as Form;

/**
 * Class News
 * @package BuscadorJuridico\Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="news")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class News
{

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="news_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     *
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="news_title", type="string", length=200, nullable=false)
     */
    public $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="news_body", type="blob", nullable=false)
     *
     */
    public $body;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="news_date_published", type="date", nullable=true)
     *
     */
    protected $datePublished;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="news_status", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     *
     */
    public $published;

}
```

I am using the `Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\SQLSrv\Driver` and the Paginator componenr of ZF2. Here is the pagination code:

```
    $query = $this
        ->entityManager
        ->getRepository('BuscadorJuridico\Entity\News')
        ->createQueryBuilder('news')
        ->select()
        ->orderBy('news.datePublished', 'desc')
        ->andWhere('news.published = true');
    $paginator = new Paginator(new DoctrineAdapter(new ORMPaginator($query)));

    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage($count);
```

But when I go to the list, I get the error:

```
SQLSTATE [42000, 8120]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Column 'dctrn_result.news_date_published_3' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

When I delete the `->orderBy('news.datePublished', 'desc')` line I get the list, but naturally not ordered. This is part of the SQL that Doctrine is generating:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  news_id_0, 
  MIN(sclr_5) AS dctrn_minrownum,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY news_date_published_3 DESC) AS doctrine_rownum 
  FROM (
    SELECT n0_.news_id AS news_id_0,
    n0_.news_title AS news_title_1,
    n0_.news_body AS news_body_2,
    n0_.news_date_published AS news_date_published_3,
    n0_.news_status AS news_status_4,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY n0_.news_date_published DESC) AS sclr_5 
    FROM news n0_ 
    WHERE n0_.news_status = 1)
  dctrn_result 
  GROUP BY news_id_0
```

With MySQL the code works. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually have a PR open to fix this. I'll see if I can poke that along.

https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/818

Answer (score 0):

I used the PR from wschalle and created my own Mssql Driver included the fix, maybe it help you.

https://github.com/kokspflanze/GameBackend/tree/master/src/GameBackend/DBAL